# singularities of higher dimensional toric sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, singularity

Is there any (general) theory on singularities of higher dimensional toric sections. I mean singularities of an intersection of an n-tori with a linear space. So for example singularities of the variety defined by 
\begin{align*} 
 x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1 \\
 x_3^2 + x_4^2 - 1 \\
 x_5^2 + x_6^2 - 1 \\
 2\cdot x_1 - x_3 \\
 x_4 + x_5
\end{align*}
I'm mostly interested in a way to find them. I tried approaches with the principal minors of the jacobian. But there are soon (if you go to higher dimensions of the tori and/or linear spaces) too many polynomials, to compute a groebner basis.

I would very much appreciate a pointer to a resource of some kind, if there are any.

kind greetings,
Marc